# how to pull out list of all hyperlinked people on a persons wikipedia page using SPARQL and dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to pull out a list of all the "persons" which have a link to another person on Wikipedia.

For instance, George H. W. Bush has this sentence in his bio:

```
"Bush was born in Milton, Massachusetts, to Senator 
Prescott Bush and Dorothy Walker Bush."
```

Now Dorothy Bush is hyperlinked to her own page. Can I get a list which looks like:

```
George H. W. Bush | Dorothy Walker Bush
George H. W. Bush | Babe Ruth
George H. W. Bush | Bill Clinton
```

and to extend this.. for everyone on Wikipedia? I'll obviously have to break this down into bit sized chunks for it to output but I just am not sure how to code this to select for linked persons only. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way to start would simply be to search for connected resources that are both of type Person. You can use [dbpedia's web based query form](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).

```
SELECT ?person1 ?p ?person2
WHERE { 
   ?person1 ?p ?person2. 
   ?person1 a foaf:Person. 
   ?person2 a foaf:Person.
}
ORDER BY ?person1
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 0
```

You can "split this data into chunks" by using the `ORDER BY` keyword and iterating over the value after `OFFSET` (eg. 10, 20, 30, ...). You should save all results of these seperate queries and then combine them afterwards to get the full result.

If you are only looking for a particular kind of interperson relationship on dbpedia, the following query will give you all the properties used to connect two persons.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p
WHERE { 
   ?person1 ?p ?person2. 
   ?person1 a foaf:Person. 
   ?person2 a foaf:Person.
}
```

Choose one or several of those properties, eg. `http://dbpedia.org/property/married`, and get a list of person related by this property using the following query.

```
SELECT ?person1 ?person2
WHERE { 
   ?person1 <http://dbpedia.org/property/married> ?person2. 
   ?person1 a foaf:Person. 
   ?person2 a foaf:Person.
}
ORDER BY ?person1
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 0
```

As you will see by yourself property usage on dbpedia is quite heterogeneous, so it might take some effort to get what you want.

Hope this helps as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this is a starting point but isn't there a way to pull out just the linked people on their profiles? I presume they have these links because of some underlying property which is hidden and hard to select through a query?

Comment: @Griff The answer provides the easiest way to pull out "just the linked people" from DBpedia. If you need more links, you need to scrape Wikipedia yourself or add more mappings to DBpedia. On Wikipedia everything is text; some of it is text in links, but only in infoboxes and (other) templates the link texts start to get meaning. That is why DBpedia extracts the information almost exclusively from Infoboxes and when it does, the meaning of the link is saved in a property. And these can be queried fairly easily using SPARQL. Hope this explains :)

Comment: How would I go about scraping Wikipedia pages for the links between content manually? Say for a given field, Mathematics? You could then truncate the search at a particular depth away from your starting node and build up some interconnectivity.